# Compactness in terms of convergence of ultra filters

Tags: filters

I'm reading this [article](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/article.php?sid=936) on Matheplanet. I have trouble with the following theorem:

> Satz 5 : Ein topologischer Raum X ist genau dann kompakt wenn alle Ultrafilter auf X konvergieren

> Translation : A topological space $X$ is compact exactly when every ultra filter on $X$ converges.

How can an ultra filter converge? I thought ultra filter was like a collection of subsets, and as far as I know, there is no idea of convergence of "subsets" in topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, a filter $\mathcal{F}$ converges to a point $x$ iff $\mathcal{F}$ contains all neighbourhoods of $x$.

Comment: So, aren't the open nbhd of X, X itself? So wouldn't all spaces be compact as the filter converges always into nbhd of X

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: What does it mean for a filter to converge to whole X then @Klaus

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Filters converge to points, not to sets. So your question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom No, the theorem is true. It says that $X$ is compact if and only if every ultrafilter converges to some $x \in X$. That is, for every ultrafilter $U$ there is an $x \in X$ such that $U$ contains all neighbourhoods of $x$.

Comment: ohhhh okay. That answers everything